# Input fields are not getting cleared on refresh

Tags: php, html, forms, refresh

I created a simple calculator using PHP. Now when I load it for the first time, all the input fields are empty. Once I type in input fields and then submit, It shows the output. Now, on refreshing the page, the page remains the same. I want the page to look like I loaded for the first time, everything blank after I refresh the page. Please tell me how to do that?

**Page on loading page for the first time:**
[image: Page 1: page on loading page for the first time]

**Page after filling input fields and click submit:**
[image: Page 2: page after filling input fields and click submit]

**Page after refresing the page:**
[image: page 3: page after refresing the page]

I want the page after refresh like Page 1, but it's coming like page 3. Please help.

Comment: please add debugging details by providing your code. Also, what does your question have to do with `apache`? If you use an Apache Server should be irrelevant to the question.